# How hook touch event globally and know X Y position of a touch?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

Need pickup the position  X  Y of touch over the screen on Windows 10, outside of my wpf app.
I read in some post can use RegisterPointerInputTarget

I try redirect all touch to my app.
Is supposed use RegisterPointerInputTarget  should so easy as the code I show, bu not work no idea what I doing wrong.

Also I found some working code like this; https://github.com/yingDev/WGestures/blob/master/WGestures.Core/Impl/Windows/TouchHook.cs

There is some way to global hook touch events and know position X Y when touch happen?

I should use RegisterPointerInputTarget?

I appreciate any info and or code example.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;




 namespace WpfApp17
 {

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {

    public enum PointerInputType
    {
        POINTER = 0x00000001,
        TOUCH = 0x00000002,
        PEN = 0x00000003,
        MOUSE = 0x00000004,
    }
    [DllImport("User32")]
    static extern bool RegisterPointerInputTarget(IntPtr hwnd, PointerInputType pointerType);


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IntPtr hWnd = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
        var ok = RegisterPointerInputTarget(hWnd, PointerInputType.TOUCH);

    if (!ok)

       {
           MessageBox.Show("Error!" );
          return; 
      }
      else
      {
         MessageBox.Show("TouchHook Redirected.");
      }


  }


  }
```

}